# Tensorflow model.summary() not showing layers information

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, functional-programming, transfer

I have an issue when using Keras's functional API to perform transfer learning. The summary() function does not show layers of the information of the new model.
Here is the code that I run to import the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 
from keras.models import Model
model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16()
model.summary()
```

As expected, the output is correct:

```
Model: "vgg16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_4 (InputLayer)         [(None, 224, 224, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      1792      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 224, 224, 64)      36928     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 112, 112, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     73856     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 112, 112, 128)     147584    
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 56, 56, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       295168    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 56, 56, 256)       590080    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 28, 28, 256)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       1180160   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 28, 28, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 512)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)        (None, 14, 14, 512)       2359808   
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 7, 7, 512)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              102764544 
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 4096)              16781312  
_________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)          (None, 1000)              4097000   
=================================================================
Total params: 138,357,544
Trainable params: 138,357,544
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Now here is the code I use to perform transfer learning by removing the model's last 2 layers:

```
model2 = Model(model.input, model.layers[-2].output)
model2.summary()
```

Here is the output:

```
Model: "model_8"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
Total params: 134,260,544
Trainable params: 134,260,544
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

All information relative to the layers has disappeared... Is this normal behavior from the functional API?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mix `tensorflow 2.x` and standalone `keras`. You should use

```
from tensorflow import keras 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model # < --- import from tf
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works when I import the "Model" class like this. Do you know what causes this behavior?

Comment: This is how it should be imported if you have `tf 2.x`.  The `keras` is now part of the `tf` and no more a standalone package. Hope that helps. And don't forget to give an [hat](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17668390/119629168-935cb980-be2f-11eb-88eb-6b7e82bb522b.png) :)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this with tensorflow version 2.5.0. It doesn't show the layer info.
so import like this.

```
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Model(....)

model.summary()
```